# python IndexError: list index out of range, matrix calc

Tags: python, range, out

I am trying to solve 1st step from Numeric Matrix Processor (hyperskill.org). I have to write program (without using numpy) which takes 2 matrix and then if number of rows and number of columns are equal I have to output sum of these 2 matrix. I know that for now number of columns is not used (only in if condition) but it doesn't matter. The problem is "IndexError: list index out of range" after I call summing function. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thx for helping!

```
main = []
main2 = []
final = []
mat = []


def reading():
    print("rows:")
    reading.rows = int(input())
    print("columns:")
    reading.columns = int(input())

for i in range(reading.rows):
    mat = input().split()
    mat = list(map(int, mat))
    main.append(mat)
return main


def reading2():
    print("rows:")
    reading2.rows = int(input())
    print("columns:")
    reading2.columns = int(input())

for i in range(reading2.rows):
    mat = input().split()
    mat = list(map(int, mat))
    main2.append(mat)
return main2


def summing():
    if reading.rows == reading2.rows and reading.columns == reading2.columns:
        for i in range(reading.rows):
            for j in range(reading.columns):
                final[i][j] = main[i][j] + main2[i][j]
                print(final[j][i], end=" ")
            print()
    else:
        print('ERROR')


reading()
reading2()
summing()
```

Comment: where did your `reading.rows` come from? from the snippet you posted it seems `reading` is defined as a function?

Comment: It's all code I have. I thought that I should wirte "reading2.rows" if I want to have access to this var later. If not. How can I get this numbers of rows from functions if I want to compare them later?